# Hint to solve the following summation identity

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, summation

Let $\overline{u}$, $\overline{v}$ and $m_{uv}$ be defined as follow:

$$\overline{u}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}u_i$$
$$\overline{v}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}v_i$$
$$m_{uv}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(u_i- \overline{u})(v_i- \overline{v})$$

Can you please give me a hint that helps me proof that the following identity:
$$m_{uv}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(u_i-\overline{u})v_i$$ is true?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
m_{uv}&= \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}(u_i−\overline{u})(v_i−\overline{v})
\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(u_i−\overline{u})v_i-\overline{v}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(u_i−\overline{u})
\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(u_i−\overline{u})v_i-\overline{v}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_i-n\overline{u})
\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(u_i−\overline{u})v_i-\overline{v}(n\overline{u}-n\overline{u})
\\
&=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}(u_i−\overline{u})v_i
\end{align}

Comment: Is this a "hint that helps (the OP) (prove) the following identity"?

Comment: Hint $\ne$ full solution.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, this is a full solution. Note that the OP asked for a hint, not a full solution.

Comment: *Just read the question* (or simply the title...). "Full solution is better than hint." No.